# How can i check the checkbox onItemClickListener event of listivew in android?

Tags: android

Explanation:
           I tried more but not got the perfect solution as per my expectation.
I want to check by checbox on the click of listview row in BaseAdapter??.

AcCategoryAdapter.java

```
public class AcCategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Activity activity;
    private List<AcCategory> acCategoryList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public AcCategoryAdapter(Activity activity,List<AcCategory> acCategoryList){
        this.activity=activity;
        this.acCategoryList=acCategoryList;
        inflater=(LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.acCategoryList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.acCategoryList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class Holder{
        TextView txtCategoryName;
        ImageView ivImg;
        CheckBox cbCooling;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final Holder holder;
        if(convertView==null){
            holder=new Holder();
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.ac_problems_list,parent,false);

            holder.txtCategoryName=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_cooling);
            holder.ivImg=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_img);
            holder.cbCooling=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_cooling);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder=(Holder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        final AcCategory acCategory=acCategoryList.get(position);
        holder.txtCategoryName.setText(acCategory.getName());

//        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                Toast.makeText(activity,acCategory.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                holder.cbCooling.setChecked(true);
//            }
//        });
        return convertView;
    }
```

list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_cooling"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_img"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_desc"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cooling" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_cooling"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/txt_cooling"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_cooling"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:button="@drawable/checkbox_checked"
            android:checked="false" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

above is the list row where i have ImageView,TextView and CheckBox and it is inflated into my adapter

Here is the call of adapter from the activity

```
lvProblem.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.e(TAG,"LISTVIEW SELECTED ITEM:-"+acCategoryList.get(position).getName());
            }
        });
```

Additional, i get the functionality like it's check from the onItemClickListener and checkbox itself.

Please, help me to solve out this problem.

Comment: I would recommend you to make this in the AcCategory.class
Simply add a boolean for checked or not to the object, and when the item is clicked, change the boolean of this object to true/false, and notifyDataSetChanged, Then in adapter getView part, if the boolean is true, just set the check box to checked

Comment: You better use custom adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You may add a parameter in AcCategory.class, just like:

   ```
   boolean isChecked = false;
   ```
2. You need to set the isChecked variable to true/false in OnItemClickListener

   ```
   lvProblem.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           // retrieve your relative item
           <your adapter>.getItem(position).isChecked = !<your adapter>.getItem(position).isChecked;
       }
   });
   ```
3. In your adapter, you need to add the checkbox in your getView method

   ```
   <your check box variable>.setChecked(acCategory.isChecked);
   ```
4. Everytime you make change, you need to call

   ```
   <your adapter variable>.notifyDataSetChanged();
   ```

Comment: Every time you make change to  private List<AcCategory> acCategoryList;, you need to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged in order to redraw the UI of the list

Comment: Are you sure isChecked is define insid the AcCategory.java?

Comment: isChecked is needed to be defined in AcCategory as you need to use it in the adapter, and each check is referenced to each AcCategory item object

Comment: <your adapter>.getItem(position).isChecked = !<your adapter>.getItem(position).isChecked consider this line if i define isChecked in AcCategory model class it's not accessible here because you directly try to access the isChecked variable.

Comment: MyAdapter is AcCategoryAdapter.getItem(position).isChecked// here is the problem

Comment: For ((AcCategory)AcCategoryAdapter.getItem(position)).isChecked, simply set isChecked as a public variable.

If you need it as a private one, you need to add the setter and getter method for this variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120117/discussion-between-milan-gajera-and-s-w).

Answer (score 0):

U have to create a byte variable .when ever u click on checkbox and its cheked then set its value one otherwise set zero.and check its value on bindview.
and notify your list.